# Get all contacts from a group in gmail

Tags: c#, gmail, contacts

I have several groups in my gmail account and I want to get for each group the assigned contacts. to get the groups, I use the following code:

```
        RequestSettings rs = new RequestSettings("TEST", "user@gmail.com", "password");
        // AutoPaging results in automatic paging in order to retrieve all contacts
        rs.AutoPaging = true;
        ContactsRequest cr = new ContactsRequest(rs);

        Feed<Group> fg = cr.GetGroups();
```

now I want to get the assigned contacts (for example group "Friends"), but I have no idea how to get them? any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can use the standard user query mechanism and just specify the group:

```
public void PrintDateMinQueryResults(ContactsRequest cr)
{
  ContactsQuery query = new ContactsQuery(ContactsQuery.CreateContactsUri("default"));
  query.Group = //The group atom id
}
```

From [Google API Docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_contacts_using_query_parameters)